# Add hint of duration for each iteration in tqdm

Tags: python, tqdm

I have a list of tasks that each take a different amount of time. Let's say, I have 3 tasks, with durations close to 1*x, 5*x, 10*x. My tqdm code is something like:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

def create_task(n):
    def fib(x):
        if x == 1 or x == 0:
            return 1
        return fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2)
    return lambda: fib(n)

n = 1
tasks = [create_task(n), create_task(5*n), create_task(10*n)]
for task in tqdm(tasks):
    task.run()
```

The problem is that tqdm thinks each iteration takes the same amount of time. As the first takes approximately 1/10 of the time, the ETA is unreliable.

**My question**: is it possible to somehow add a hint to tqdm to inform how much each iteration takes compared to the first? Something like informing the duration weights of each iteration...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If "create_task" can be modified, the "inspect" library can help.

```
import time
from tqdm import tqdm
from inspect import currentframe,getargvalues

def create_task(n):
    '''
    On my computer, "tqdm" cannot handle the Fibonacci sequence.
    '''
    # def fib(x):
    #     if x == 1 or x == 0:
    #         return 1
    #     return fib(x - 1) + fib(x - 2)
    def func(x):
        time.sleep(x)
    return lambda: func(n), getargvalues(currentframe()).locals['n']

n = 1
tasks = [create_task(n), create_task(5*n), create_task(10*n)]

bar = tqdm(enumerate(tasks), total=len(tasks), desc=f"Takes 1 times as long as the previous loop.")
for idx, (task, curr_n) in bar:
    bar.set_description(f"Takes {curr_n/n:.2f} times as long as the first loop.")
    task()
```

Comment: Hi 黃駿傑, I think I got the point of your suggestion: use inspect as a workaround to fetch the value of n in each iteration. However, it is easy for me to have an "array of weights" for the duration of the tasks. What has not been solved is: can we provide such information to TQDM so it consumes it when calculating the ETA? (I know I can use the description field, as you showed, but that's an informal solution - the ETA would still be incorrect).

BTW, welcome to StackOverflow!! I suggest that you explain the logic of your solutions besides providing the code, in future answers you write ;)